# Optimize Joomla SQL Query to store data in array and pass on array output to field

Tags: mysql, jquery

I have built 2 queries

```
$id = JFactory::getApplication()->input->getIn('vid');
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$db->setQuery("SELECT `email` FROM `#__usedcar_variants` WHERE `id`='$id' LIMIT 1");
$_POST['form']['Email'] = $db->loadResult();

$id = JFactory::getApplication()->input->getIn('vid');
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$db->setQuery("SELECT `mobile` FROM `#__usedcar_variants` WHERE `id`='$id' LIMIT 1");
$_POST['form']['Contact'] = $db->loadResult();
```

However - it seems not the best way for optimization, as ideally

1. both the email and mobile can be collected in a single query,
2. store them in an array,
3. then assign each array value to the correct field

Can someone help pls on it

Comment: @Lodder - sure, thanks for noticing that. could you advise how to combine them to array. You are a real professional as i have gained by reading replies in joomla community

Comment: see my answer below. I believe that's what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for multiple queries in your case. You can simply select `email` **and** `mobile` from the table, like so:

```
$id = JFactory::getApplication()->input->getInt('vid', '');
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select(array('email', 'mobile'))
      ->from($db->qn('#__usedcar_variants'))
      ->where($db->qn('id') . ' = ' . (int)$id)
      ->setLimit(1);
$db->setQuery($query);

$results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

The `$results` variable is now the **object** that contains the results.

If you want to access them, simply do the following:

```
$something_1 = $results->email;
$something_2 = $results->mobile;
```

**Note:** I've also corrected `getIn` with `getInt` (it should have a `t` on the end)